# How to minimize the standard deviation in Or Tools?

Tags: python, or-tools, scip

I have a list of air routes with their length in minutes and the passenger demand. I want to arrange them in 168h circuits where the standard deviation of a circuit is as low as possible.

I found this resembles the [multiple knapsacks problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/pack/multiple_knapsack) and so that's my basis. I've got the 168h circuits but the demand is randomly assigned because of the current objective (maximize total demand within a circuit).

As advised in [or-tools - Compute the stdev from a SumArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313934/or-tools-compute-the-stdev-from-a-sumarray) I'm actually trying to minimize the sum of abs(val - average).

This is what I came up with but I realized that I'm minimizing the sum of abs(val - average of ALL routes). How do I compute the average demand in a circuit and add it to the formula ? It's also become painfully slow with this change, which I'm not sure why.

```py
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
if solver is None:
    print('SCIP solver unavailable.')

# Variables.
# x[i, b] = 1 if item i is packed in bin b.
x = {}
for i in data['all_items']:
    for b in data['all_bins']:
        x[i, b] = solver.BoolVar(f'x_{i}_{b}')

# Constraints.
# Each item is assigned to at most one bin.
for i in data['all_items']:
    solver.Add(sum(x[i, b] for b in data['all_bins']) <= 1)

# The amount packed in each bin has to match it's capacity.
for b in data['all_bins']:
    solver.Add(
        sum(x[i, b] * data['weights'][i]
            for i in data['all_items']) == data['bin_capacities'][b])

# Objective.
# Maximize total value of packed items.
objective = solver.Objective()
for i in data['all_items']:
    for b in data['all_bins']:
        objective.SetCoefficient(x[i, b], abs(data['values'][i] - round(np.mean(data['values']), 0)))

objective.SetMinimization()
status = solver.Solve()
```

Thank you